# what does the flag means in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am a new at tensorflow, and I have read some code from its website. I was wondering what is the `FLAGS` means in the code?

for example, in line 78 of [fully_connected_feed.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py), the inputs are `FLAGS.batch_size`, `FLAGS.fake_data`. Then I read this in the definition of `FLAGS`:

```
# Basic model parameters as external flags.
FLAGS = None
```

I was confused about this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is used to store command line parameters. Checkout these lines:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
      '--learning_rate',
      type=float,
      default=0.01,
      help='Initial learning rate.'
  )
... 
FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
```

You can also see it lets you define default values and create a help description on the command line so others know what parameters accepts your cli without having to look at the code.